# Where to call _gaq.push Google Analyticss in MVC form?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, google-analytics

I have a MVC form in my Razor view using Html.BeginForm and in my submit button i was adding the code for Google Analytics in the onclick event like this:

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'MyStuff', 'AperturaForm', 'VeinteMasLed']);"
```

but my problem is that if the forms submits but it gets an error, the click event was fired and the push was made even if the form fail.
So my question is, do i have to perform this _gaq.push in the onsubmit form event like `@using (Html.BeginForm("20mil", "Product", null, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "small", onsubmit = "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'MyStuff', 'AperturaForm', 'VeinteMasLed']);" }))`?

What are my choices?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use a default button with the onclick event and then call an function like this:

```
$.ajax({url: '@Url.Action("myAction", "myController")',
     data: { field1 : $('#txtExample').val() },
     type: 'POST',
     success: function (data) {
     if (data.actionCompleted) {
          _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'MyStuff', 'AperturaForm', 'VeinteMasLed']);
     }
     else {
          alert('Error');
     }

}
});
```